# YQL Finance for Currencies - missing info

Tags: json, yahoo, yql, finance

So taking EURUSD for example if you go to the [main currency page](http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json) you see that yahoo not only provides you the current rate but also the change on the day and the change in percentage terms. this is the same info they provide for stocks (stocks obviously have other  metadata like market cap).

YQL is meant to be the method we are able to access this in mobile apps for JSON use, and we are blessed with [a full list of properties](https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/enumQuoteProperty) ([also this list](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm)) to query. However it seems that this stuff only works for stocks, because if you do

[select * from csv where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=c1l1&s=USDEUR=X";](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20csv%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc4l1%26s%3DEURUSD%3DX%2CGBPUSD%3DX%22#h=select+%2a+from+csv+where+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fd%2Fquotes.csv%3Fe%3D.csv%26f%3Dc1l1%26s%3DUSDEUR%3DX%22%3B)

only the `l1` property works, i.e. the last price, whereas the `c1` property just shows N/A. This is odd since the info is *clearly* there on the website. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: and yes, i've read the other yahoo finance related questions and recognize that yql isn't officially supported, however i feel that this change-on-day info is so readily available on the main webpage that it really should be available via yql if i could just query the right thing

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a closing price for a currency exchange rate, because there is none, which is inherent to the financial system.
A stock traded at a specific market like NYSE has a closing price, because the market closes at a given time. And has an opening price the next trading day.
A currency exchange rate will not close its trading. When NYSE goes offline, other markets in Asia or Europe still trade the currency.
So with the query you will only get the actual exchange rate at that given time. And I think that's why you will not get a historical quote for an exchange rate as well.